# Java Socket Programming frame not responsive and loopy request

Tags: java, sockets, jframe, serversocket

I'm trying socket programming for the first time and try codes from https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/SocketProgramming/SocketProgram.html and implement it to a frame. Clients can connect to the server, but there are some problem with my server frame like it's not responsive. And the request handler is ok for the first use per client, and not working for the next request. I notice that the handler looks like having a loop which I don't know why it's happening.

[How the server react when the request made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfOVF.jpg)

This is how I start the server

```
private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(8005);
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
            System.out.println("Waiting for clients");
            while (true) {
                socket = server.accept();
                Runnable worker = new RequestHandler(socket);
                executor.execute(worker);
                System.out.println("check executor");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally{
            if(executor!=null){
                executor.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
```

The request handler

```
public class RequestHandler implements Runnable {
  private Socket socket;
  ServerSocket server = null;

  public RequestHandler(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

      String userInput = in .readLine();
      while (userInput != null) {
        System.out.println("Received Message from " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + userInput);
        jtaLog.append("Received Message from " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + userInput);
        writer.write("You write : " + userInput);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And from the client program the request made like this

```
private void btnSendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  try {
    String message = tfMessage.getText();

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    out.println(message);
    jtaLog.append( in .readLine() + "\n");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
  }
}
```